# accessing model manager methods in datamigration

Tags: django, django-south, data-migration

I am trying to formulate a datamigration for one of my apps. I am using the reputation system mentioned here - [django-reputation](https://github.com/teknolab/teknolab-django-reputation/tree/master/reputation)

in my `forward` method, I have the following code -

```
orm['reputation.reputation'].objects.log_reputation_action(user = user_x, originating_user = user_y, action_value = 10, target_object = sample_obj)
```

but while running the migration, I get the following error -

```
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'log_reputation_action'
```

I have freezed the `reputation` app in the datamigration. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible.

From the [South documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html):

> You can do a lot more with this inside a data migration; any model can
>   be available to you. **The only caveat is that you won’t have access to
>   any custom methods or managers on your models**, as they’re not
>   preserved as part of the freezing process (there’s no way to do this
>   generally); you’ll have to copy any code you want into the migration
>   itself. Feel free to make them methods on the Migration class; South
>   ignores everything apart from forwards and backwards.

Comment: guess I would have to have to do it the ugly way. thanks for the citation!!

Comment: If you are only going to migrate forwards - you can import from the real models. Just beware that it will mean that this migration can only be applied now. I've used this with a datamigration taking a complicated calculated thing and turning that into a real column.

Answer (score 4):

Since Django 1.8, you can include model managers in migrations by adding the use_in_migrations property.

From the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#model-managers

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    use_in_migrations = True

class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()
```

Comment: Just make sure to read up on the consequences of this approach first. "References to [...] and model manager declarations with managers `having use_in_migrations = True` are serialized in migrations, so the functions and classes **will need to be kept around for as long as there is a migration referencing them**." Excerpt from the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#historical-models) with custom highlights.

Comment: Does someone have a full example of this to share please ?

Answer (score 2):

Augmenting @mattdedek's answer with an example of use in a migration

```py
def my_migration_function(apps, schema_editor):
    MyModel = apps.get_model('my_app_name', 'MyModel')
    MyModel.objects.create(name='foo')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(my_migration_function),
    ]
```

Currently works in django migrations (tested on version 3.0.4)